# Vuex module state undefined

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

I'm a little confused over vuex modules.

I have a Vue component, which I show on a search page:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="filtersPanelActive">
        Filters panel
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["filtersPanelActive"])
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```

I then have a store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import searchPage from "./modules/searchPage.js";
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    artPage,
    legalsPage,
    searchPage
  }
});
```

and a search page store:

```
const searchPage = {
  state: {
    filtersPanelActive: false
  },
  actions: {},
  mutations: {
    toggleFilters(state) {
      state.filtersPanelActive = !state.filtersPanelActive;
    }
  },
  getters: {}
};

export default searchPage;
```

But nothing is quite working... In my vuex dev tools I have the following:

```
{
   "artPage":{
      "startDate":false,
      "endDate":false,
      "confirmBooking":false
   },
   "legalsPage":{
      "filesUploaded":[

      ]
   },
   "searchPage":{
      "filtersPanelActive":false
   }
}
```

But when I inspect the Vue component it shows the following:

[image]

Why do I get undefined? I'm slightly overwhelmed by vuex, namespaces, modules etc, so feel free to over explain...

In another component I use

```
this.$store.commit("toggleFilters");
```

And its worth noting that that 'works' – as in the vuex state changes from `true` to `false`, however my `mapState` still isn't pulling through anything. So the module seems to be loaded correctly.

Answer (score 4):

**2018-06-05 MINOR UPDATE:** Updated the `mapState` code to something slightly simpler.

Two things to add to your code to enable namespaces and to make sure you are referencing the right module.

In your `searchPage` module, add the `namespaced: true` property to the export as such:

```
const searchPage = {
    namespaces: true,
    state: { ... },
    ...
}
```

This enables namespacing for the module and makes it self contained and reusable.

Then in your search page component change your `mapState` to this:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('searchPage', [ 'filtersPanelActive' ])
}
```

This will map the component variable `filtersPanelActive` to your `searchPage` module state variable `filtersPanelActive`. Your `v-if="filtersPanelActive"` line in your template should work now.

Let me know if this fixes things for you and if it doesn't please let me know and I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually did the following: `...mapState({
      filtersPanelActive: state => state.searchPage.filtersPanelActive
    })` and the namespaces weren't necessary :)

Comment: Hey you should answer your own question if that solution worked for you.

Also, I don't get this. mapState should work with the shortcut of simply adding an array of items, which would assume the global namespace. But it doesn't. I'm going to try your method.